# How to update/overwrite an existing rig with Rigify

Tags: armature, rigify

I have rigged a character with Rigify. I would like to adjust some bone positions (edit the armature). The documentation states I can adjust the metarig and then again press Generate Rig. The default action should overwrite the existing rig. I have also tried enabling 'Advanced Options' and selecting the current rig (https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Rigging/Rigify#Advanced_Rig_Generation)

However, 'Generate Rig' gives the following error:

```
Incorrect armature for type 'utils'
Can't add new bone 'root' outside of edit mode.
```

I only found 1 answer, stating to rename the existing 'rig'. But this will generate a new rig, unparented to the mesh and with no weight painting.

How can I adjust/overwrite an existing rig?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I've found my own answer right after posting this question :)

I had moved my metarig to another layer and when pressing 'Generate Rig' the layer with the rig itself was not active. So make sure to have both the metarig and the rig active when pressing 'Generate Rig'.

'Generate rig' now correctly overwrites my existing rig, keeping the parenting and skinning intact. Only my pose position gets reset, but that's not a problem.